# Will annihilation occur when two electrons and a positron are released at once to collide against each other?

Tags: photon-emission

suppose  free Two electrons and a positron are released at once in space to collide against each other,will there be annihilation ?or there will be no annihilation due to imbalance of matter and antimatter?

Answer (score 0):

Charge is conserved. You have two electrons of charge -1, a positron of charge +1, so the total charge is -1. Whatever the end state is, it will have charge -1. You can have the positron annihilate one electron, for an end state of a single electron, total charge -1.